# How to integrate mocking framework with Specflow

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, integration-testing, specflow

I am looking to do some end to end testing using specflow.

I have a windows service that picks up various files, does some processing, prints out those files and then moves said files to a success or failed archive folder.

I don't want to actually print the files out during my tests so thought that instead I could use a mocking framework to mock the result of the print operation for my tests.

I have used a number of mocking frameworks for my unit testing in the past but not used one alongside specflow.

I am not sure the best/easiest way to integrate the two. I have seen mention of creating a specflow binding file and use the [beforescenario] tag to initialise and do my mocking code in that method.

Would this work? Is there anything else I would need to do? Is there a better solution?

Rough example of test

```
@BizTalk
Feature: Printing_Push
    Tests Printing

Background:
    Given all test data is stored under C:\TestData\XXXXXXXXXXXX

@HappyFlow
@SysTest
Scenario: Printing_HappyFlow_Success
    When the file is copied
        | Property      | Value                            |
        | Source File  | XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.dat                        |            
        | Target Folder | C:\Temp\XXXXXXXXX  |
    Then 1 files expected with extension dat will appear in the C:\xxxxxxxxxxxxxx folder within 10 seconds.
```

A filesystem watcher picks up the file. It is then processed before being printed and then the file is moved to an archive folder. The test will initiate this process by dropping file into expected file location. The test does not directly call the code.

Comment: What have you tried already? Have you settled on a mocking framework? When you say "print out those files" do you mean literally print something using a printer?

Comment: Hi. Yes, Literally printing a file to a printer. I was thinking I could mock this method to avoid actually printing the file out and just returning true or false.

Comment: Not settled on a mocking framework as i am happy to use any framework but I imagine if it can be done with one framework it can be done with any and it is just a question of whether the integration with Specflow is possible.

Comment: Can you post a sample scenario? I think this is possible, it is just hard to come up with a solution without seeing your scenario. I also take it the scenarios will be working directly with the classes used in the windows service, like a unit test?

Comment: The code that you put in `[beforescenario]` will run before each scenario of feature files. I think if you are able to successfully mock the printing part in your code then it should work in `[beforescenario]` annotation also.

Comment: Updated with skeleton example and bit more context